# When I test my app with a real product ID, I can only pay with a test card

Tags: in-app-purchase, ads, in-app-billing

My app displays ads and I want to give the user the ability to block the ads by making an in-app payment. So I added in-app purchasing and tested it with test product IDs; the fake credit card is displayed and everything looks good. However, when I changed the product ID to match the real one I configured in Google Play and try to complete the purchase, I'm still seeing the fake card:

[image]

I couldn't find any similar questions on Stack Overflow, so I assume my problem is unique. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create test products for testing, you can make test purchases with the final product, in this way you should do it to the test the whole process.
In fact there is no option in the Play Console to mark an in-app product as a test product.

What causes the test card to be shown is that the google account from which the purchase is made is in the list on : Google Play Console >> Settings >> Account details >> License Testing

Comment: You're right about they're being no way to mark an in-app product as a test product, but that's not what I was asking. I know that test products are defined in the app and I had tested that way. The problem is that after I change the product ID in my app to match the real product ID as defined in Google Play Console->Store presence->In-app products, I'm still getting the fake card when I try to make the purchase.

Comment: As for the License testing list, the account in question was not in it.